# window is not defined Angular Universal 10

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-universal

I'm working on Angular 10 application, After implementing SSR getting the below error

```
/Users/a1410978/Desktop/ssr-workspace/asfc-shell/dist/server/main.js:260991
const _window = window ? window : {};
                ^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Module.../asfc-shared/src/lib/tagging/mi.values.ts (/Users/a1410978/Desktop/ssr-workspace/asfc-shell/dist/server/main.js:260991:17)
```

In **mi.values.ts**

```
const _window = window as any ? window as any : {};
const cid_global = _window['cid_global'] ? _window['cid_global'] : {brand: 'unknown', locale: {country: '', language: ''}, ENV: '' };
const z_application = cid_global.accessPath && cid_global.accessPath.slice(1,cid_global.accessPath.length-1);
const z_host = cid_global['brand'].toUpperCase();
const z_country = cid_global.locale.country;
const z_language = cid_global.locale.language;
const contrastPreference = cid_global.contrastPreference;
const z_converged = 'BW';
const z_env = cid_global.ENV;
let lastPageTitle = 'unknown';

/* istanbul ignore next */
export const analyticsDefinitions = {
  /**
   *  Event tagging general
   ********************************************************/
  'onclick': {
    'dl': 'userevent',
    'z_event': 'clicked',
    'z_application': z_application,
    'z_host': z_host,
    'z_country': z_country,
    'z_language': z_language,
    'z_converged': z_converged,
    'z_env': z_env,
    'z_client_id': maskClientId(getCidConfigParams('clientId')),
    'z_referer': getCidConfigParams('source'),
    'z_redir': getCidConfigParams('redirectUri'),
    'z_login': 0
  },
```

I'm aware that, using `isPlatformBrowser` will resolve my problem, but I'm sure how to use it in a constant file.

Please guide me

Comment: Have you tried with mocking this using `domino` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/domino)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can also use that check but in the right way:

```
// Consider as client side
const isClient = typeof window !== 'undefined';

let cid_global;

if (isClient) {
  // You will write your client initialization here, so you don't have check window anymore
  cid_global = window['cid_global'] : {brand: 'unknown', locale: {country: '', language: ''}, ENV: '' };

  // More to come
}
```

Comment: now i'm getting this error `const cid_global = typeof _window['cid_global'] !== 'undefined' ? _window['cid_global'] : { brand: 'unknown', locale: { country: '', language: '' }, ENV: '' };
                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'cid_global' of undefined`

Comment: No. I'll update the answer to help you to be clear about which work you would proceed in browser and server

Comment: But  I added inside the `if` statement `export const analyticsDefinitions = {` dosn;'t work it throws error

Comment: It looks like you have to returns 2 different values for 2 sides. You're supposed to take care yourself cause I have no idea about your business logic.